# How to execute command on host machine in Virtualbox

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine

My guest machine is Ubuntu 14.04 and my host machine is Windows 8.1.

I need to execute a command coming from Linuxmachine on Windows.
What is the best idea to do that? If my host was also Linux, I could set up SSH server and easily use it to remote control. But in my situation it's slightly more difficult.

Comment: There are numerous SSH servers for Windows. You could also use OpenSSH with Cygwin. Microsoft even provides another protocol: Telnet. But without knowing what you want to achieve we can't give you more precise solutions.